# How can I call a C# DLL in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

A DLL is created in C# to get realtime data from server. The data will be processed with algorithm developed in C++ (it is due to C++ is better for machine learning than C#). how to make system work? any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752029/calling-c-sharp-dll-from-c, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728325/can-you-call-a-c-sharp-dll-from-a-c-dll

Comment: There are a lot of ways, directly calling functions from the DLL, sharing the data via pipe, socket or shared memory or even writing and reading an ASCII or binary file. It depends on your use case, what the best solution is